# angular price range filter not working

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, filter, angular-filters

I have made a price range filter, and when the checkboxes are clicked, I want to show only those items that have the price falling in the price range specified by the checkbox

This is what I am following - http://jsfiddle.net/65Pyj/

HTML

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="includePrice('0,700')" ng-checked=""/> Rs 700 and Below <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="includePrice('701,1500')" ng-checked=""/> Rs 701 - 1500 <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="includePrice('1501,3000')" ng-checked=""/> Rs 1501 - 3000 <br/>
     <input type="checkbox" ng-click="includePrice('3001,5000')" ng-checked=""/> Rs 3000 - 5000 <br/>
     <input type="checkbox" ng-click="includePrice('5001,100000000')" ng-checked=""/> Rs 5001 and Above
</div>
```

In the controller, I get the min and maximum of each checkbox into an array and again min and max of that array as the lower and upper limit

Controller

```
$scope.priceIncludes = [];
$scope.ranges = [];

$scope.includePrice = function(pricerange) {
    var i = $.inArray(pricerange, $scope.priceIncludes);
    if (i > -1) {
        $scope.priceIncludes.splice(i, 1);
        ranges = pricerange.split(',').splice(i, 1);
    } else {
        $scope.priceIncludes.push(pricerange);
    }
    var arrayString = $scope.priceIncludes.join();
    var rangeArray = arrayString.split(',')
    $scope.maxRange = function( rangeArray ){
        return Math.max.apply( Math, rangeArray );
    };
    $scope.minRange = function( rangeArray ){
        return Math.min.apply( Math, rangeArray );
    };
    $scope.ranges[1] = $scope.maxRange(rangeArray);
    $scope.ranges[0] = $scope.minRange(rangeArray);
}

$scope.priceFilter = function(searchResult) {
    if ($scope.priceIncludes.length > 0) {
        if ((parseInt(searchResult.fees) >= parseInt($scope.ranges[0])) && (parseInt(searchResult.fees) <= parseInt($scope.ranges[1])))
            return;
    }
    return searchResult;
}
```

When I use

```
filter:priceFilter
```

it returns random results which fall out of the selected min and max limit.

Comment: I have used parseInt to convert..should it work then

Comment: Create a demo that replicates problem

Comment: @charlietfl - sorry, I could not do this earlier - I have created a fiddle. What is happening is, it is returning results without the filtered items instead of only the filtered items - https://jsfiddle.net/da60e8zg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to return the value if the condition is true.
Not the other way around.

```
$scope.priceFilter = function(searchResult) {
        if ($scope.priceIncludes.length > 0) {
            if ((parseInt(searchResult.fees) >= parseInt($scope.ranges[0])) && (parseInt(searchResult.fees) <= parseInt($scope.ranges[1])))
        return searchResult;
        } else {
        return searchResult;
        }
    }
```

Comment: when I did this...but no change...same behaviour

Comment: yes this works, but I wanted to display all result if nothing is selected

Comment: Simply return the value if priceIncludes is empty. Check the updated code in answer.